# Magento 2 product export 503 error Server Unavailable

Tags: php, magento, export, magento2, magento2.2

I am trying to export about 5500 products from Magento 2 and I'm receiving a 503 error. I've increased the PHP memory limit to 2GB in the `php.ini` and `.htaccess`

```
.htaccess
    php_value memory_limit 2048M
    php_value max_execution_time 372000
```

Apache has been restarted as well. But I still am receiving the `503 error`. How can I fix this issue?
The last known error I received from the system.log that was for this was

```
[2018-02-27 10:01:55] main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size: 100000; Allocated memory size: 2300000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 6442450944 bytes.
```

I have fixed this following the advice from 
[magento2 decrease batch size of catalog_category_product](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/211415/magento2-decrease-batch-size-of-catalog-category-product/211421#211421)

There seem to be no errors being logged in the magento directory, but the 503 error still seems to happen on product exports. The file eventually shows up in the database for download, but there is no automatic download when exporting.

After about 30 seconds into the export I am shown this error.

> **Service Unavailable** The server is temporarily unable to service your
>   request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try
>   again later.

Comment: just a question: are you sure it is using the correct php.ini? but actually the .htaccess should have priority over it...

Comment: Yeah, I am positive is is correct in the php.ini, and set to 2GB of data.
"The PHP pool memory_limit is set to 2 GB, the config file was changed on Feb 7." Oh I thought .htaccess didn't have priority, good to know.

Comment: I'm not sure about it, but i think i remember about it... please check before keeping it as good :) don't want to mess your things more